# JQuery Autocomplete submitting the data while press return

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I'm using JQuery Autocomplete (bassistance) and have run into a problem. if i select by pressing ENTER(Return key) it just displayed in the text box and i need to press one more enter to search (submit the form) is there is any way to make the form submit on single select....

Answer (score 4):

```
$("#inputbox").keypress(function() {
var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);// use which if , no support for keycode
if(code == 13) { //Enter's keycode
    return false;
}
});
```

this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `result` function to submit the form once you have selected a value.

```
 $('#textbox').autocomplete( ...your data and options... )
              .result( function(e,data,formatted) {
                   $('#textbox').value( formatted );
                   $('form').submit();
               });
```

I don't recall off the top of my head, but I think that the `result` handler will be called instead of the default action of filling  the input so I think you'll need to stuff the value in the input before submitting as I've shown.

Comment: `$("#q").autocomplete('?hl=suggestions', {
 .result( function() {
  width:350,
  max: 10,
  highlight: false,
  scroll: true,
  scrollHeight: 300,
  selectFirst: false,
  autoFill: true,matchContains: true,
  minChars: 0,  
  formatResult: function(data, value) {
   return value.split(".")[0];
  }
  
       $('form').submit();
          });

 });`